# How to force MySql not to locking all tables used in a trigger

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, triggers

Suppose we have two tables, `messages (msgid , mbody)` and `logs (logid, lbody)`. We add an `AfterUpdate` trigger on `messages` as follows:

```
BEGIN
    if new.msgid = 7 then
        do sleep(20);
        UPDATE logs SET lbody = 'test' WHERE logid = 5;
    end if;
END
```

Then, we update the row with `msgid = 7` and it sleeps for 20 seconds.
Meanwhile, we want to update a random row in `logs` but we must wait until the sleep ended because the entire `logs` table is locked!!

In practice, I encountered a very huge problem while triggering some processes since all of the used tables were locked.

Is there any way to explicitly say to MySql not to lock all rows in all tables used in a trigger?
Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: @Solarflare, Thanks for your comment. Yes, I tested it multiple times. I tried using two computers connected to the database via an SSH connection using MySQL Workbench. Then I updated the `messages` table using the first computer and tried to update the `logs` using the second one. The second connection waits 20 sec for the first one to finish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of exploring, I noticed that the engine of `logs` table was `MyISAM` not `InnoDB` and that was the cause of locking.
I simply changed it and the problem solved.